Error when trying to install wagtail from source
11:36
I'm new to Wagtail and want to learn to contribute. But after many manipulations, when I do setup.py, there appears an error stack with at the end : string or bytes expected.
Here is the full message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d_drive/var_docs_complements/open-source-contribs/wagtail/./mysetup.py", line 81, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/ainaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 102, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/ainaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 70, in _install_setup_requires
    dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
  File "/home/ainaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 52, in __init__
    super().__init__(filtered)
  File "/home/ainaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 297, in __init__
    for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1021, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 459, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1018, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 943, in _normalized_name
    or super()._normalized_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 622, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 871, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
Thanks.

I did some searchs. Also, I tried using github codespace and got very different results. I expect to be able to build and run it from source in my local computer. Thanks.

The setup instructions for Wagtail do not involve running setup.py.

check what setuptools and pip it requires

I now try to install through pip install -e ."[testing,docs]" -U

I now try to install with pip install -e ."[testing,docs]" -U . But it returns the same error.

thank you very much all ! I messed up with virtual environments. For now, everything is clear. Thanks.

I messed up with virtual environments. I redid all the process and everything was done right. Thank you very much all.

The answer does not really show how you "redid the process".
